# Gerrit user access to only assigned changes

Tags: configuration, gerrit

I am configuring a Gerrit instance in our lab. We will use this one for code review assignments for the students. Since many of the students may receive same code to review, I want to customize the access to the review requests in such a way that the students can only see code review requests posted/assigned to them.

Please let me know if Gerrit supports that? If supports, please let me know how to configure that. Thanks

Comment: I assume that all students are working on the same repo..? If not, it would be easy.

Comment: Yes, all students are using same repo.

Comment: You can have different branches (or refs) for each of them. The token `$username` is replaced with the current username and you can use that in the access control setup. I think that could work out. You just have to allow you/teacher/tutor to read all of them.